# Using query set to filter displayed models

Tags: python, django

I am still very new to Python and Django. I have a custom user model. I want to display only model data that was created by a specific user. I have tried the following, but does not work. Please understand I am still learning.

**Model**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nodisoapp:home')
```

**View**

```
class CreateCompany(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    login_url = '/scrty/login/'
    form_class = forms.Companyform
    template_name = 'nodiso/create_company.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(CreateCompany, self).form_valid(form)
        self.object.user.add(self.request.user)
        return response
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.user = get_object_or_404(models.Company,user)
        return models.Company.filter(user=self.user)
```

**Template**

```
{% if company_list %}
    <h1>Please select your company</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for company in company_list %}
      <li>{{company.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'nodisoapp:createcompany' %}">Create New Company</button>
      <a href="{% url 'nodisoapp:createcompany' %}">create</a>

      {% else %}
      <h1>You have no companies</h1>
      <a href="{% url 'nodisoapp:createcompany' %}">create</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'nodisoapp:createcompany' %}">Create A Company</button>
      {% endif %}
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the currently logged in user the way to do that is to use

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Company.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I changed the code, but it still shows all of the data, should it be added only in the views?